# AccountContactRelation SOQL returning null with dynamic filter values

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, accountcontactrelation

I am trying to fetch AccountContactRelation recordsrelated to specific accountId from Lightning component via server side call. I am passing the AccountId as a param to the apex controller. But unfortunately the query returns null. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code  of the apex controller class:

```
doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log('v.recordId----------->'+cmp.get("v.ClientId"));
    var action = cmp.get('c.getrecs);
    action.setParams({"AccountId": cmp.get("v.ClientId")});
    action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
    cmp.set('v.acrrecords', response.getReturnValue()); 
    }
    else if (state === "ERROR") {
    }
    }));
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}



 @Auraenabled
   public static list<AccountContactRelation> getrecs(String AccountId){       
    list<AccountContactRelation> acr = [select id,AccountId from AccountContactRelation where AccountId  =:AccountId  ];

     return acr;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you run the query separately in developer console with correct accountId? are you getting any result?

Comment: Does the running user have permission to view the records involved? Is the class running `with sharing` or `without sharing`?

Comment: Can you check the variable name? AccountId in Apex should be same as what you are using in JS controller. You can try running it in workbench if that helps and there is a valid account-contact relationship.

Comment: Hi Guys, Yes I ran the query in developer console with hardcoded Id and it returns records. Yes have permissions to view records and the variable name is also exactly matching with the JS controller in lightning component

Comment: Have you tried putting a debug log in the method to see if you are receiving the account id or not? If not, then you can try that, and in that case can you also update your post to include how you are setting the *AccountId* in your JS and passing it to the aura controller.

Comment: Yes I did check if AccountId was passed to Apex controller and it did . Added JS controller code also to the post. And Just FYI when I hardcoded AccountId value in place of dynamic variable in SOQL filter, its returning records.

Comment: I assume its just a typo? *var action = cmp.get('c.getRecords');* as your apex method is *getrecs*. Can you confirm?

Comment: Sorry my bad, its just a typo here. Its correct in my sandbox...checked all typo errors already :(

Comment: Does [this account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/44477) also belong to you? Please do not create or maintain duplicate accounts.

Comment: I tried the same query and same approach and it works just fine. You need more debug statements all across your flow to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed the single quote. Please see your code;

```
var action = cmp.get('c.getrecs);
```

replaced with

```
var action = cmp.get('c.getrecs');
```